# rsync with 'svn rm'

Tags: svn, rsync

How I might use the rsync --delete option, but make the delete command 'svn rm'?

I have a repo of some config files and such, but those configuration files are not a working copy. I always copy them locally to a svn repo directory, excluding .svn, and then check them in.  I have changed a bunch of file names so I want to delete the old ones in the repo (svn mv would be a bit overcomplicated for this).

Edit: Oh, and if there is a svn option that will give me the same end result, that is good too.

Comment: Why? You shouldn't bother with the contents of your subversion repository. You'll lose the history of renamed files and you'll probably destroy the repo's integrity.

Comment: When you delete a file, doesn't it only delete is for the revision and keep it for the history (previous revisions), or is that not how it works?  I don't care about the diff between previous versions of these particular files.

Comment: That's how subversion works. Is there any harm in keeping those files around?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never done this, but the way I'd attack this is write a script that:

1. Runs rsync with the '--delete' option
2. Run `svn status`<sup>*</sup>
3. Collect all file names that were missing (the lines starting with '!')
4. Run `svn rm`<sup>*</sup> on that list of file names
5. You can even then do an `svn commit -m`<sup>*</sup> with a comment saying the files were delete after an rsync at said date and time.

<sup>*</sup> - using ssh to run the command remotely, if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

> svn delete $( svn status | sed -e '/^!/!d' -e 's/^!//' )
>   svn add $( svn status | sed -e '/^?/!d' -e 's/^?//' )

I found this at http://thedrupalblog.com/updating-drupal-module-subversion-integrated-filesystem-using-rsync#comment-421